# How to clone a Grakn keysapce

Tags: database, vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

If I have an existing keyspace in Grakn, how can I easily clone the keyspace to create a copy in the instance?

In the `db > cassandra > data` folder I can see a list of folders of my keyspaces. I have already created a copy of one keyspace, but this doesn't show up in Workbase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grakn 1.8 adds "the ability to export and import date and schema to 1.8 grakn in order to support migration into newer versions of grakn." [Grakn release 1.8.1](https://github.com/graknlabs/grakn/releases/tag/1.8.1)

Hence to copy an entire keyspace you can:

1. Start the grakn server: `grakn server start`
2. Create a new empty keyspace using the same schema as the original: `grakn console -k <keyspace_copy> --f <schema.gql>`
3. Export data from the original keyspace: `grakn server export <keyspace> exported_data.grakn`
4. Import the data into the new keyspace: `grakn server import <keyspace_copy> exported_data.grakn`